# Getting recorded events from an IP camera that doen't support ExportRecordedData

Tags: node.js, ip-camera, onvif

I've been researching this for 2 days but I couldn't find any solutions that are camera provider agnostic (I want to implement this only using onvif), so let's say I have an IP camera that detects motion and captures recordings based on the detection, I was able to use `PullMessages` method to get notifications for onvif events, but problem is the camera doesn't support `ExportRecordedData` to allow me to export these recordings, so does anyone know of a way to get access to an IP camera's sd card content using onvif?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some cameras can stream recorded video. You could try `GetRecordings` for get RecordingToken's, and then call `GetReplayUri` with some token. In reply you'll get link to record's stream.